# Using GitHub API to determine if the last commit to master was a result of a merged pull request?

Tags: github, github-api

We use GitHub flow as branching strategy which means that anything in master is the result of a merged pull request. It's trivial to get the last commit by doing the following.

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:org/:repo/git/refs/heads/master
```

However it seems non-trivial to work out the pull request that caused this commit.

Is it possible to find out the pull request that created this commit via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PR should be one of the parents—the second one—of the commit in master, since that commit is the result of a merge of the PR.

You can find that parent with the [GitHub commit API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:sha
```

[GitHub doesn't offer a way to get the branch from a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062772/6309), but you could [list all the PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) and cross-reference the SHA1 found above with said PRs.

Comment: So is the second parent always the tip of the branch that was merged into master? 
I can search for the Pull Request using a URL like this: `GET https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=<sha1>+is%3amerged`
This shows any pull request that contains that commit and has been merged. I'm wondering if this will always work. It is possible the commit would be in more than one pull request I would think.

Comment: @Jacob yes, the second parent is the one being merged.